# Rails debugger does not work after setting up breakpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-debug-ide

Ruby 3.1.1
Rails 7.0.3

After breakpoint is enabled debugger fails.
With no breakpoint runs ok.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to remove gem 'debug' from Gemfile.